# "too many SQL variables" error when using smbinning

Tags: sql, r, binning

I'm trying to use `smbinning` function in R to find the best breaking point of a continuous variable, but I get

> `Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : too many SQL variables`.

Take this simple dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(tenure = rnorm(100,50,16), yn = rbinom(100,1,0.3))
str(df[,c('yn','tenure')])
```

This results in:

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ yn    : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ tenure: num  90.5 50.6 32.7 59.6 42 ...
```

so the data types are fine. However, when I run `smbinning`:

```
library(smbinning)
result=smbinning(df,y="yn",x="tenure")
```

I get the error messages.

I have tested smbinning with other data and it works fine, but I cannot find what is wrong in this particular case.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error - smbinning runs with provided data (through there is a column name error in your `str()` call.

Comment: @Peter_Evan yeah, I can use the function with other data as well, but there must something that sometimes triggers this error and I didnt find anything in the package.